# getProcAddress in python for linux?

Tags: python, linux

I'm working on a linux system. I know how to use nm and other gnu binutils, but I want to know if there is a better way to resolve function addresses using python. I don't want to have to parse a text response from a system call if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the function with type related, use `ctypes`. Or if you want to cal it dynamicaly without any types, use `dl`

```
import dl
dl.open("/lib/libc.so.6").call("time")
```

If you want to get symbol of function, use `sym`.

Comment: So for further detail, I'm trying to use python ptrace and set a debug point at the address of a function call. So what I'm looking for is something akin to GetProcAddress in the windows api.   I think I can achieve this by using a syscall to one of several differnt utils like nm or objdump but I was hoping there is a better way of doing this.